# Deserialize a JSON property into a given class

Tags: jackson

I can deserialize a JSON array

```
"[{...}, {...}, {...}]"
```

into a particular class by doing this

```
mapper.readValue(jsonString, Station[].class)
```

However, in reality my JSON looks like this

```
"{stations: [{...}, {...}, {...}]}"
```

I would simply like to select the "stations" property and deserialize it like before, but I have been unable to find any examples or useful information in the javadocs as to how one is supposed to achieve this!!

Some pseudo-code might look like

```
mapper.readValue(jsonString.stations, Station[].class)
```

Although obviously this would not work.

I have tried reading the JSON into a JsonNode, from there I can select the stations using node.get("stations") but how then do I convert this to an array of Station???

I'm amazed that I have to open an SO question for something so trivial... Gson is much more usable but this is a legacy product.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a JSON string like this:

```
"{\"stations\": [{...}, {...}, {...}]}"
```

Then you can deserialize it by using a [`TypeReference`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/type/TypeReference.html):

```
Map<String, Station[]> map = mapper.readValue(jsonString,
                                              new TypeReference<Map<String, Station[]>>(){});
Station[] stations = map.get("stations");
```